# Maven package .bat script: how to add a delay?

Tags: maven-2, scripting, batch-file

I have this .bat script which I use to maven package my application. Problem is, just after it ends execution, it closes the console window. The last 2 lines somehow are completely ignored.

Does anyone know the trick to make this work?
I just want to have a quick check if the build was successful.

```
@echo off
cls
cd C:\svn\project
mvn package -o -P local
sleep 3
pause
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try to write

```
call mvn package -o -P local
```

Comment: Great! The "call" before the maven command solved my problem of executing two maven calls from one batch file. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that I found [here](http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2007/11/wait-or-pause-in-windows-batch-script.html):

```
ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
```

This will ping an unreachable host with a pause in between.  Also the standard output is redirected so you don't see it in your output.  Not the best solution but will work in a pinch.

Comment: I don't think the OP's problem is to add a delay, but that mvn somehow avoids additional commands to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools provides a command line sleep function:

http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html